# Why does alert($("#myHTMLElement")) display its original properties even though I already mutated it via an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this function which is supposed to create a checkered board.

```
function createBoard() {

    let strHTML = "";
    let alphabets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];

    for (var row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
        strHTML += "<div>";
        for (var column = 0; column < 8; column++) {
            if ((column + row) % 2 === 0) {
                strHTML +=
       `<div class="white_square" id="${alphabets[column]}${8-row}" onclick="test()"></div>`;
            }   
        } 

     //   .... omitted some code for clarity
};
```

Here is the function that "mutates" the css background color of a white square to green.

```
$("#blackPawn").click(function() {
    createBoard();
    $("#a6").css("background-color", "green");
    alert($("#a6").css("background-color"));
});
```

Here is the function that gets called when a square is clicked. If the square is green it should say something like "congrats", otherwise it'll just state that it's a white square.

```
function test() { 

    if ($(".white_square").css("background-color") === "rgb(0, 128, 0)") {
        alert("good job eric");
    } else {
        var k = $(".white_square").css("background-color");
        alert(k);
    }
}
```

The line

```
alert($("#a6").css("background-color"));
```

Says that "#a6"'s background-color property now has the value "rgb(0, 128, 0). However when I click on that square triggering the test() function, it says it has the value rgb(255, 255, 255). Why is this the case?

Comment: Could you maybe create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You have many elements with the class `white-square`. `$(".white_square").css(...)` only operates on the first in the document. [*"Get the computed style properties for the **first element** in the set of matched elements."*](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css1)

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on the [jQuery `css` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/) explains (emphasis mine):

> Get the value of a computed style property *for the first element* in the set of matched elements [...]

Although `a6` is a `.white_square`, it is not the first one. While here, you really check only the background color of the first one:

```
$(".white_square").css("background-color") === "rgb(0, 128, 0)"
```

and also in the `alert` that follows.

Solve this by selecting the clicked square:

```
$(this).css("background-color")
```

or:

```
$(ev.target).css("background-color")
```